springBoot + Thymeleaf: UTF-8 in properties
I have this config file:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
}

in the application.properties I have defined: spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
the template:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:lang="${#locale.language}" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
...
</html>

but I see this on the browser:


You don't need the messageSource Spring Boot already adds one, you can specify the encoding through spring.messages.encoding (which defaults to UTF-8` already).

Is your messages.properties file encoded in UTF-8 ?

save all the files with an external editor as UTF-8
